# If $\phi(t) \geq 0$, then $\lim_{t \to x} \phi(t) \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As the title suggest, If $\phi(t) \geq 0$, then $\lim_{t \to x} \phi(t) \geq 0$. Where $\phi$ is a real valued function defined on $(a,b)/{x}$ and I’m assuming $\lim_{t \to x} \phi(t)$ exist.

**My attempt:** Assume towards contradiction i.e $l= \lim_{t \to x} \phi(t) \lt 0$. Since this limit exist, we have $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 : 0 \lt |t-x| \lt \delta, t \in [a,b] \Rightarrow |\phi(t)-l| \lt \epsilon$. Now, take $\epsilon=|l|$, then $l-\epsilon \lt \phi(t) \lt \epsilon+l=0$. So we have $\phi(t) \lt 0$ for some t. Which contradicts our initial assumption.

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. Also you should include assumption that $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: Perhaps you should write that $l-\epsilon<\phi(t)<\epsilon+l=0$ holds for $t\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. Regarding the comment by @kcjkgs - there is no need for continuity, since the limit $\lim_{t\to x}\phi(t)$ is assumed to exist.

Comment: @kcjkgs It is not given that $\phi$ is continuous. Only existence of a finite limit at $x$ is given.

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: Yes, I missed the assumption on existence of the limit.

Comment: @jakobdt $t \neq x$

Comment: @user264745 Right. Then it holds for $t\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\setminus\{x\}$.